# How secure is a PublicKey in an Android Hardware-Backed keystore?

Tags: android, security, android-keystore

If I generate a public/private keypair in the Android KeyStore, is the PublicKey treated with the same level of security as the PrivateKey by the operating system? (Irrespective of what I then do with the Key in my app)

Answer (score 1):

The public and private keys are both stored in secure hardware.  However, while there is no way to export the private key, the public key can be extracted.  Assuming the device isn't rooted or otherwise compromised, only your app can extract the public key.  Even if the device is compromised in some way, the private key won't leave the secure hardware.